# Add images to Canvas in C# ( Windows Phone 8)

Tags: image, canvas, windows-phone-8

How can I add an image to a canvas ? I trieds this but the images doesn't appear

XAML

```
<Canvas x:Name="Row3" Canvas.Top="140" Canvas.Left="220" Height="400" Width="80">
    <Border Height="100" Width="70" BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="3" />
</Canvas>
```

C#

```
Image test = new Image ();
BitmapImage b = new BitmapImage();
b.UriSource = new Uri("/Asstes/Deck/34.png", UriKind.Relative);
test.Source = b;
test.Height = 100;
test.Width = 70;
Row3.Children.Add(test);
```

Answer (score 2):

Like igraly suggested, try to use Canvas.Set...
Moreover, check if you included that image in your project.

**Project->Set existing item**

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this?

```
Canvas.SetLeft(test, 10);
Canvas.SetTop(test, 20);
Row3.Children.Add(test);
```

And are you sure your image is loaded correctly? I see that you wrote **Asstes** when you probably meant **Assets**

Answer (score 0):

this book might be helpful to you-
Read chapter 4
http://www.charlespetzold.com/phone/index.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set as canvas background image it will be helpful.

XAML code

```
<Canvas>
  <Canvas.Background>
     <ImageBrush x:Name="imagebrush" Stretch="Uniform">
          <ImageBrush.RelativeTransform>
               <CompositeTransform Rotation="0" CenterX="0.5" CenterY="0.5" />
          </ImageBrush.RelativeTransform>
     </ImageBrush>
  </Canvas.Background>
</Canvas>
```

C# code

```
BitmapImage bmp = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/Assets/AlignmentGrid.png", UriKind.Relative));
imagebrush.ImageSource = bmp;
```